# Using matrices and 3 rotation angles for $x,y,z$ axes, how can you compute the final position of a point in 3D?

Tags: matrices, rotations

Seeing that the three individual rotation matrices for each axis are not commutative, I was wondering how a point (e.g. $[1,2,3]$) could be rotated in 3D space with a single matrix as to avoid the "commutative" issue.

Comment: Have you considered how does it should be in 2D?

Comment: Well, 3D rotations are inherently non-commutative, unlike 2D rotations. If you imagine a solid object instead of a single point, you can imagine that the final orientation of that object would depend on the order of the rotations. So really the question is this: how do you want the object to be oriented after the rotation? You can always rotate straight from start to finish, but you'll have no control over the final orientation.

Comment: For this rotation to be well-defined, you also have to specify in which of the six possible orders the primitive rotations should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

A point is rotation can be described with either of two scenarios, each requiring three pieces of information to fully describe:

1. [Three sequential rotations about fixed axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davenport_chained_rotations). For example $$ \mathrm{R} = \mathrm{RZ}(\varphi)\,\mathrm{RY}(\psi)\,\mathrm{RZ}(\theta)$$

   This is described by the three angles $\varphi$, $\psi$ and $\theta$. These are called Euler angles.
2. [A single rotation about an arbitrary axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation). For example $$ \mathrm{R} = \mathrm{Rot}(\hat{u}, \theta)$$ where the unit direction vector $\hat{u}$ needs two quantities for description (like longitude and latitude) and the third quantity is the angle $\theta$. This is the Rodrigues rotation formula.

[There is an alternative scenario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Quaternion-derived_rotation_matrix) to the last one using **quaternions** where four quantities $x$, $y$, $z$ and $w$ are used to represent this axis and angle. There is a constraint that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2}=1$ for this scenario to work

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \hat{u} & = \frac{ (x,y,z) }{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} } & &\text{axis} \\
  \theta & = 2 \,\mathrm{atan}\left( \frac{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{w} \right) & & \text{angle}
\end{aligned}$$